# Contact Form 7 hindi text is not showing in email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Users filled the form in hindi but in email the form is not showing the text only english is coming and the fields filled in hindi are showing blank.

Answer (score 0):

Hindi script requires a utf8 compatible font.  the font on your website is utf8 compatible since you can see the script on the form.  However, the email reader you are using has a non-utf8 font which displays the hindi characters as blank.

Comment: i am using gmail, but still it is not showing hindi text.

Comment: how are you sending the email?  Directly from your server, or are you using an SMTP plugin?  Some mail servers will not handle [utf8 encoding](https://support.google.com/mail/forum/AAAAK7un8RUBRSi6PAn6oA/?hl=en-GB) properly.